# WooCommerce Rest API get completed orders completed after date

Tags: php, rest, woocommerce

With the [woocommerce rest api](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-orders) for getting orders I can filter by `status = completed` and `after=SOMEDATE`; but the `SOMEDATE` value is publish date and NOT completion date.

Is there a way to get completed orders after a completion date of `SOMEDATE`

Comment: looking for the same. Have you found a solution?